# Microsoft Translate - The type or namespace name 'DataContract' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, web-parts, translate

I'm trying to implement the C# code for a Sharepoint web part using Microsoft Translate API, found with sample code here.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512421.aspx

I've managed to solve other problems, but when i tried to deploy, i get 10 errors concerning to the DataMember and DataContract related lines. I'm new to .NET and C#, i hope i can get some help here. I have tried this several times, i didn't get this error before though i got stock with other reference problems. Now that i recreated, i get this error.

```
The type or namespace name 'DataContract' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

This is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Web;
using System.Media;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MyTranslatorTool.MyTranslator
{
    public partial class MyTranslatorUserControl : UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AdmAccessToken admToken;
            string headerValue;
            //Get Client Id and Client Secret from https://datamarket.azure.com/developer/applications/
            //Refer obtaining AccessToken (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx) 
            AdmAuthentication admAuth = new AdmAuthentication("clientid", "gpOGezhz/1dX6hgR6QZhG2j0Z45vw4HlnMWOwr2gNeA+");
            try
            {
                admToken = admAuth.GetAccessToken();
                // Create a header with the access_token property of the returned token
                headerValue = "Bearer " + admToken.access_token;
                TranslateMethod(headerValue);
            }
            catch (WebException er)
            {
                ProcessWebException(er);
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }

        }
        private static void TranslateMethod(string authToken)
        {
            //original text = text
            //translated text = translation
            //original language = from
            //destinating language = to
            string text = "Use pixels to express measurements for padding and margins.";
            string from = "en";
            string to = "de";

            string uri = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text) + "&from=" + from + "&to=" + to;

            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authToken);
            WebResponse response = null;
            try
            {
                response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    //translated text
                    System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer dcs = new System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(Type.GetType("System.String"));
                    string translation = (string)dcs.ReadObject(stream);
                    Console.WriteLine("Translation for source text '{0}' from {1} to {2} is", text, "en", "de");
                    Console.WriteLine(translation);
                    //push to view
                    //alpha.Text = translation;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (response != null)
                {
                    response.Close();
                    response = null;
                }
            }
        }
        private static void ProcessWebException(WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.ToString());
            // Obtain detailed error information
            string strResponse = string.Empty;
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response)
            {
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII))
                    {
                        strResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Http status code={0}, error message={1}", e.Status, strResponse);
        }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class AdmAccessToken
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string access_token { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string expires_in { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string scope { get; set; }
    }

    public class AdmAuthentication
    {
        public static readonly string DatamarketAccessUri = "https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13";
        private string clientId;
        private string cientSecret;
        private string request;

        public AdmAuthentication(string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            this.clientId = clientId;
            this.cientSecret = clientSecret;
            //If clientid or client secret has special characters, encode before sending request
            this.request = string.Format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&scope=http://api.microsofttranslator.com", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(clientId), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(clientSecret));
        }

        public AdmAccessToken GetAccessToken()
        {
            return HttpPost(DatamarketAccessUri, this.request);
        }

        private AdmAccessToken HttpPost(string DatamarketAccessUri, string requestDetails)
        {
            //Prepare OAuth request 
            WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(DatamarketAccessUri);
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestDetails);
            webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            using (Stream outputStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(AdmAccessToken));
                //Get deserialized object from JSON stream
                AdmAccessToken token = (AdmAccessToken)serializer.ReadObject(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
                return token;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding a reference to: [System.Runtime.Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.aspx)

Comment: Can you help me on this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350678/translatortool-translator-translatorusercontrol-is-not-allowed-here-because-it